# Call a custom function inside cx_Oracle

Tags: python, json, cx-oracle

I have a custom function in Oracle Locator and I will use this function inside cx_Oracle to transform my SDO_Geometry in GeoJSON!

```
import cx_Oracle
import json

connection = cx_Oracle.Connection("TEST_3D/limo1013@10.40.33.160:1521/sdetest")

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT a.id AS building_nr, c.Geometry AS geometry, d.Classname AS polygon_typ FROM   building a, THEMATIC_SURFACE b, SURFACE_GEOMETRY c, OBJECTCLASS d  WHERE  a.grid_id_400 = 4158 AND a.id = b.BUILDING_ID AND b.LOD2_MULTI_SURFACE_ID = c.ROOT_ID AND c.GEOMETRY IS NOT NULL AND b.OBJECTCLASS_ID = d.ID""")
obj = cursor.fetchone()
obj = obj[1]
print obj

result = cursor.callfunc('sdo2geojson', cx_Oracle.OBJECT, [obj])
```

My object looks like : cx_Oracle.OBJECT.
This function is working inside SQLdeveloper.

When I call the function I get the following error:  *cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Variable_TypeByValue(): unhandled data type cx_Orac
le.OBJECTVAR*

What I´m doing wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This capability is available in the currently unreleased version of cx_Oracle. You can get the source from https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_oracle.

Comment: it i still not working. it is written _"InterfaceError: object type not associated with bind variable"_ what is wrong?

Comment: This is a limitation. You can create a variable using cursor.var() and use that as the return type. It should be possible to pass an object type there as well but that isn't currently supported.